# httpClient.get is undefined when using dynamic function/observable references

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I asked a question a few days ago and got some headway on a solution, however now I'm stuck at another wall I'm unsure how to get over.

I have two parent components, a shared view/component with an extended base component, and a service all hooked together.  The objective is to use the two parent components to drive what data is shown within the shared component.  The two parent components use references to service methods passed into the shared component to get the data.

I've reached an issue where my http.get is always undefined no matter what I try.  I've instantiated it like I do in my other services but I've had no luck. I suspect this is caused by how i pass in my service references.  Code below:

**Parent Component Code:**

```
// PARENT COMPONENT
myData$: Observable<myType>;
searchMethod: Function;

constructor(private myService){
    this.myData$ = this.myService.myData$;
    this.searchMethod = this.myService.searchData;
}

// PARENT COMPONENT HTML
<app-shared-component 
[myData$] = "myData$" 
[searchMethod]="searchMethod">
</app-shared-component>
```

**Shared Component Code:**

```
export class MySharedComponent extends BaseComponent<MyType> implements OnInit {

@Input() myData$: Observable<myType>;
@Input() searchMethod: Function;

constructor() { super(); }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$ = this.myData$;
}

search(): void {
    this.searchMethod().subscribe(//do something);
}
```

**Base Component Code:**

```
@Input data$: Observable<T>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$.subscribe((response: T) => //do something);

    super.ngOnInit();
}
```

**Service Code:**

```
private myDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<MyType>(new MyType());

get myData$(): Observable<MyType> {
    return this.myDataSubject.asObservable();
}

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

searchData(): Observable<void> {
    return new Observable<void>(observer => {
        this.http.get<MyType>(
            'http://myuri'
        ).subscribe(
            response => {
                // do something
            },
            () => observer.error(),
            () => observer.complete()
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put a console.log() of the data in your response? Is there any data returned?

Comment: @JD333 It never actually hits the response. It just throws 
"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" when logging this.http and rolls through the subscribe.

Comment: .. not sure.. which angular are you using?

Try this..     method() { this.http.get(yoururl).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });}

Comment: Call "method()" wherever you want. If that works, you can just create a Subject that get's set to the return response. Then subscribe to it from wherever.

Comment: I'm using Angular7. That just throws the same error since this.http is undefined.  I'm going to try adding () => decorators for the functions being passed in.  I think this might an issue with how HttpClient gets its context.

Comment: Hah, and as soon as I added the () => decorator to searchData in my service, it went through and pinged my controller! Thanks for your help @JD333 but I think I've solved the puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're losing the context of your service when you set `this.searchMethod = this.myService.searchData` in your parent component. It should work if you change `searchData() {` to an arrow function: `searchData = (): Observable<void> => {`.

Comment: This was exactly my issue, thanks for figuring that out! Welcome to the community btw!